# How to resize or adjust position of elements in html and css,

Tags: html, css

I was making a website with HTML and CSS with specific set positions, different widths, and heights for every div but when I open the website on different screen size devices some of the layout changes and no longer align with my needs. What is the best practice to make the website consistent and auto-resize when the screen size changes? An example would be appreciated too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks up responsive Webdesign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@test-doe provided a solid answer.

What you're asking about can be resolved in many ways. While CSS Flexbox and Grid are both amazing CSS tools, they can be a bit complex for beginners.

**I first started responsive design using a CSS tool known as a "media query".**

This article lightly digs into media queries with an explanation and examples you can play with:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

If you want to learn CSS, there are many great free tutorials on YouTube. One of the gentlest educators in the CSS space is probably Kevin Powell.
Check out one of his videos on responsive CSS here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ohtVzCSHqs

Good luck on your adventures into responsive CSS!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **Responsive Web Design** and there are multiple ways of achieving it.

You could try using:

- **percentages instead of px**

Or some more modern ways such as:

- **css flexbox**
- **css grid**

**Here are some very good tutorials on the subject:**

- flexbox - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_responsive.asp
- grid - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp
- flexbox complete guide - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- grid complete guide - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
- flexbox vs grid - https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/03/30/should-i-use-grid-or-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

CSS does feature a resize element that allows users to adjust elements both horizontally and vertically. Kind of like this:

```css
div {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```